# Exibir a lista completa de tabelas numa conexão Oracle com Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle

Como eu faço para em uma conexão com o banco Oracle, mostrar todas as tabelas. fiz uma conexão e tenho mais de 500 tabelas no banco e só mostra 74, que as três que eu preciso para montar a POC que eu estou fazendo, não estou conseguindo mapeá-las.

veja as tabelas que aparecem. Como estão em ordem alfabética, as tabelas que eu quero, começam com POC e observe que na letra P não tem nenhuma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer colocar as 500 em um modelo do entity? Tentou fazer com botão direito no projeto, add, new item, data, entity data model? Aí cria a conexão e escolhe as tabelas.

Comment: Não, como eu disse apenas três que não aparecem na lista. Somente 3 tabelas que eu desejo mapear.

Comment: Depende do usuário que você usou pra logar. As 500 tabelas estão todas no schema de um mesmo usuário?

Comment: Sim, antes de eu fazer rodar no Entity, na conexão mostrava todas e depois que instalei o ODAC e fiz funcionar a conexão dentro do Entity, não aparece mais. Antes também não aparecia, então apareceu uma opção de New Query e mais alguma coisa, não lembro mais do restante e setei e apareceu todas. Agora essa opção não está mais disponível para mim.

Comment: Cada troca de usuário exige que você faça uma conexão nova.

Comment: Mas eu não troquei de usuário. aqui na empresa, para os desenvolvedores, é apenas um usuário e um esquema para todos e somos mais de 15.

Comment: O que pude ver é o seguinte. Ele(conexão) mostra um esquema que não existe. Ela criou o nome do esquema, o mesmo nome do usuário, assim. Usuário: ts_sistema e esquema ts. E na conexão está assim: usuário: ts_sistema e esquema: ts_sistema. Fiz um select dentro da conexão para trazer a tabela que quero com o esquema da conexão e não veio nada. Troquei o esquema(no select) e consegui exibir os dados da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi. Depois de muita mexida, vi que na conexão, abrindo ela, há uma aba chamada Filters. Nela, entre algumas opções, há uma que podemos acrescentar e remover schemas. Adicionei o schema desejado e agora pude mapear as três tabelas que necessitava.